# Find the time and height of an airplane which flies at $400i+500j-k$ km/h

Tags: multivariable-calculus

*At midday an airplane is located at position $(3,4,5)$, and it travels at $400i+500j-k$ kilometers per hour. The pilot knows that there is an airport at position $(23,29,0)$.*

a) *Find the hour during the airplane passes over the airport. (Assume the Earth is plane and the vector $k$ points up.)*

b) *Which will be the height of the airplane when it passes over the airport?*

I have this solution:

a)

Compute the distance between the two points $A$ and $B$:

$\sqrt{(23-3)^{2}+(29-4)^{2}+(5-0)^{2}}=\sqrt{1050}$

From formula $d=\frac{v}{t}$, we get

$t=\frac{\sqrt{500^{2}+400^{2}+(-1)^2}}{\sqrt{1050}}=\frac{\sqrt{410001}}{\sqrt{1050}}$

Is this correct?

Could you also give me some ideas to solve the second part?

Comment: Your answer for (a) would be correct if the plane flew directly from point $A$ to point $B$. But this is not the case here: The plane is on a straight trajectory that takes it _over_ point $B$, not through it.

Comment: For Part (a) you must compute the horizontal distance from the plane's current position to the point $(23,29,5)$ divided by the horizontal component of the velocity to obtain the time until the plane is above the airport. For part (b) you must compute the decrease in altitude from the original $5$ km which occurs during the time found in part (a) to find the plane's height above the airport as it passes over the airport.

Comment: @JohnWaylandBales, How do I calculate distance between those two positions? Is just the difference between $y$ values (=$|4-29|$)?

Comment: Sorry I did not see your question sooner. The distance between $(2,4,5)$ and $(23,29,5)$ is computed in the normal way and the horizontal component of the velocity is $400i+500j$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*TLDR: You are really overcomplicating this. You already have the component form — use it*

**Part A**
We want the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the plane and airport to match. To solve for this, we note that the plane travels $20$ kilometers in the $x$ direction to the airport. Since the plane goes $400$ kilometers per hour, this takes $3$ minutes. The plane also has to travel in the $y$ direction, going $25$ kilometers. Since the plane travels at $500$ kilometers per hour in the $y$ direction this will take $3$ minutes also. Since the times match up we confirm that the plane passes over after $3$ minutes.

**Part B**
To find the vertical height all we have to do is plug in $3$ minutes into our velocity equation. Note that this is $\frac{1}{20}$ of an hour. I'll leave the calculation up to you!