# How calculate the horizontal distance between two vectors in $\mathbb{R^{3}}$?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

How I can calculate the *horizontal distance* between two vectors in $\mathbb{R^{3}}$.

If the two vectors are $(3, 4, 5)$ and $(23, 29, 0)$, then its horizontal distance is $25$?

Or how do I compute that distance?

Comment: What's "horizontal" here?

Comment: What is horizontal distance?

Comment: I'm trying to solve this problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1885204/find-the-time-and-height-of-an-airplane-which-flies-at-400i500j-k-km-h . Someone has suggested me calculate that distance.

Comment: I would assume that the z-component is then omitted and your are in fact casting (projection!) the points back on the xy-plane. In that case the horizontal distance is the distance formula on the x and y components, which in this case won't be 25

Comment: For Part (a) you must compute the horizontal distance from the plane's current position to the point $(23,29,5)$ divided by the horizontal component of the velocity to obtain the time until the plane is above the airport.